# How long can we keep IMPALA JDBC connection open?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, jdbc, connection, impala

We have a spark application that runs few SQLs using impala jdbc connection. The application completes in different times like 15min, 1hr and 3hr max.

Can we have the JDBC connection open till the job completes or do we need to close and open in short-time ?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I looked at this and I see no other answers so I presume IMPALA is on the wane with cloud advancements. Anyway.

1. Afaik you keep the connection open during the complete processing of the current query, that would make perfect sense. But the Spark App may have multiple Impala queries and processing in between not related to IMPALA.
2. In Spark (3) you have this JDBC parameter:

> queryTimeout  The number of seconds the driver will wait for a
> Statement object to execute to the given number of seconds. Zero means
> there is no limit. In the write path, this option depends on how JDBC
> drivers implement the API setQueryTimeout, e.g., the h2 JDBC driver
> checks the timeout of each query instead of an entire JDBC batch. It
> defaults to 0.

But this is less relevant.

3. On the server side - impalad, you have have various settings. See https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_timeouts.html#impalad_timeout/
4. These parameters are either set these to 0 or not for resource pools.
5. When you provide the jdbcURL for IMPALA via Spark, ensure you request a pool (request pool) with the appropriate settings, so you do not get a timeout. I am not sure if you can do this via Spark via sessionInitStatement (for query level), most likely you can, but you may have different queries with different characteristics.

So, it is more a config issue.